# QT: how to show linux command output in text browser

Tags: linux, qt

I want to run a Linux command programmatically and show the output in a text browser. Here is my code:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(){
QString  qstr;

FILE *cl = popen("ifconfig eth0", "r");
char buf[1024];
while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), cl) != 0) {
    qstr = QString::fromutf8(buf);
    ui->textBrowser->setText(qstr);
}
pclose(ls);
}
```

But I got nothing in the text browser. If I change `qstr` in the `ui->textBrowser->setText(qstr);` with some arbitrary `"string"`,it works fine.
Any helps?! Thanks.

Comment: I’d use QProcess and connect to `QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput()`, and append the output as it comes in.

Comment: this works even if my command was dynamic and nonstop updating? like `ping google.com`...I'm new in QT, can you reference me to an example for more details?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In you example with popen use:

```
 qstr += QString::fromUtf8(buf);
```

But better use QProcess. For dynamic output use:

```
QProcess* ping_process = new QProcess(this);
connect(ping_process, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, [=] {
    ui->textBrowser->append(ping_process->readAllStandardOutput());
});
ping_process->start("ping", QStringList() << "8.8.8.8");
```

For use lambda do not forget add in your .pro file:

```
CONFIG += c++11
```

Comment: You may use terminate() slot on ping_process.

Comment: i can't access ping_process on `on_pushButton_2_clicked()` so what should i do?

Comment: Move ping_process declaration in private scope of class declaration

Comment: for dynamic output(for example ping) this code works perfect! but when i want to show output for `airodump-ng`, non-stop printing makes the text unreadable in the text browser.... `airodump-ng` uses `fflush` and i think this it the point... what shoud i do? thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
QProcess p.
p.start("your_command");
p.waitForFinished(-1);

ui->textBrowser->setText(p.readAllStandardOutput());

// or

ui->textBrowser->setText(p.readAllStandardError());
```

much easier than unsing `popen`.

Comment: Thanks! It works fine. If i want to show dynamic output (commands like `ping google.com` or commands that has update like `airodump-ng`), what should i do?

Comment: Try following: Make `QProcess` a member variable. Start the process like above but put the reading of the output in a SLOT called by a `QTimer`. For example any 500msecs. (See other answer for a better dynamic output reader).

Comment: use of `waitFor*` is not recommended in the GUI thread, this will make the application unresponsive until there is output from the command, use the synchronous approach in Alex's answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

My function that allows some complex `shell` calls with piping using `grep` or `awk`

```
QString shell_command(const char *input) {
  QProcess p;
  QString command = QString::fromLatin1(input);
  p.start("/bin/sh", QStringList() << "-c" << command);
  p.waitForFinished(-1);
  qDebug() << "run" << command;
  auto res = p.readAllStandardOutput();
  auto err = p.readAllStandardError();
  qDebug() << "out" << res;
  qDebug() << "err" << err;
  return res;
}
```